# How to split one column into three

Tags: r, split

I'm reading in a csv file which is quite messy. It looks like `tt`.

```
a <- c("REQDO.,TRIBUNAL DE JUSTIÇA DO ESTADO DO RIO GRANDE DO SUL ,")
b <- c("29/05/1992 ,PUBLICADO ACORDAO DJ: , ,                         ,                           ,")
c <- c("23/04/1991 ,DECISAO PUBLICADA DJ: , ,        ")
d <- c("29/05/1992 ,PUBLICADO DESPACHO NO DJ , ,PROCEDO LIBERACAO PECAS P/ FORMALIZACAO ACORDAO                         ,                           ,")

tt <- rbind(a,b,c,d)
row.names(tt) <- NULL
```

For some reason I have to use `sep=";"` in order to be able to read the csv. If that wouldn't be the case I'd just read it in with `sep=","` but it seems that this is no option.

Now, I'd like to split this one column into three, that in the end `tt` looks like this:

```
V1          V2                                                     V3              
REQDO.      TRIBUNAL DE JUSTIÇA DO ESTADO DO RIO GRANDE DO SUL
29/05/1992  PUBLICADO ACORDAO DJ: 
23/04/1991  DECISAO PUBLICADA DJ:
29/05/1992  PUBLICADO DESPACHO NO DJ                               PROCEDO LIBERACAO PECAS P/ FORMALIZACAO ACORDAO
```

How can I do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `cSplit` from `splitstackshape`

```
library(splitstackshape)
res <- cSplit(tt, 'V1', sep=',')
```

Comment: @Thomas No problem.  It will also change the `class` of the column based on whether it is numeric or not.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look out for that.

Comment: @Thomas By default, `type.convert=TRUE` can change it to `FALSE` if needed.